# Twig custom filter return cached value

Tags: 9

I have a custom filter for the twig, but the value of the filter doesn't update. It remains the same till clearing the cache.
I want to get the url param and based on the value showing different output in the twig template.
Here is the custom twig filter

```php
class CustomTwig extends Twig_Extension {
    
  public function getFunctions(){
        return [
          new TwigFunction('link_to_requirement', [$this, 'linkToRequirement']),
        ];
      }
  public function linkToRequirement($title) {
    $x = $_GET['req'];
    return $x == str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
  }

}
```

Then use it as `{% if link_to_requirement(paragraph.field_title.value) %}`.

Is there any option to disable the cache for this twig filter, or should I do it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the cache context for the query parameter.

In this case you can't return it in a render array because you return only a boolean, but you can try to bubble it up:

```
$x = \Drupal::request()->query->get('req');

$twig_bubbleable = [
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['url.query_args:req'],
  ],
];

\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($twig_bubbleable);
```

Comment: Reminder: Cache contexts are ignored for anonymous users, if the "Internal Page Cache" module is enabled.

Comment: Great, thank you working fine. I added your snippet before return statement.

Comment: @Hudri, not a problem with caching based on the URL or parts of it because the URL is used as cache key.